# Lines, circles and other shapes?

Tags: pdfmake

Is it possible to draw `lines`, `circles` and `other shapes` with [pdfmake](http://pdfmake.org/#/)? If yes, is there a `documentation` or are there any samples? I would like to replace [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) with [pdfmake](http://pdfmake.org/#/).

Answer (score 17):

Yes, its possible. pdfmake calls them vectors. See
[pdfMake Vector examples](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/blob/master/examples/vectors.js) for more possibilities.

An example for drawing a line followed by a polygon:

```
{
   canvas: 
   [
       {
           type: 'line',
           x1: 40, y1: 60,
           x2: 260, y2: 60,
           lineWidth: 3
       },
       {
           type: 'polyline',
           lineWidth: 3,
           closePath: true,
           points: [{ x: 10, y: 10}, { x: 35, y: 40 }, { x: 100, y: 40 }, { x: 125, y:10 }]
       }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I answered an issue in pdfMake at GitHub like this:

Create a table with layout headeronly you must define an empty body, otherwise the line would not appear:

```
var dd = {
    content: [
        {
                                  table : {
                                      headerRows : 1,
                                      widths: [200],
                                      body : [
                                              [''],
                                              ['']
                                              ]
                                  },
                                  layout : 'headerLineOnly'
                              }
            ] }
```

The width defines the length of the line

Comment: The nice thing about this method is that you can specify widths as a percentage, like '100%' or '50%'. I didn't see that you can do that with canvas.

Comment: The line is bit too thick, how to control it's thickness?

Answer (score 3):

```
canvas: [
                {
                    type: 'rect',
                    x: 198,
                    y: -186,
                    w: 198,
                    h: 188,
                    r: 8,
                    lineWidth: 4,
                    lineColor: '#276fb8',

                },

                 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

@gegobyte i used the code mentioned by @Beka with headerRows : 0, layout : 'lightHorizontalLines' to get reduced line width

```js
var dd = [
    content: [
        {
            table : {
                headerRows : 0,
                widths: ['*'],
                body : [
                    [''],
                    ['']
                ]
            },
            layout : 'lightHorizontalLines'
        }
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use canvas to create a line**

```js
{ canvas: [{ type: 'line', lineColor: 'red', x1: 0, y1: 5, x2: 595-2*40, y2: 5, lineWidth: 2 }] }
```

Answer (score -1):

<s>As far as I know, pdfmake does not provide an drawing API. Despite this, pdfmake provides you some methods to insert images at your pdf.</s>

Best regards!